# My library isn't recognized by python 3 even though I am certain that it is installed

Tags: python

I'm certain that I have installed the library using pip and it has returned the confirmation that it has been installed. When the import command is run, it throws a ModuleNotFoundError.This problem is not exclusive to this particular library and none of the libraries that are not included in the python default package works.
The code is:
`>>> from PyQt5 import Qwidgets Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: cannot import name 'Qwidgets' from 'PyQt5' (C:\Users\Franklin Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\__init__.py)`

Comment: Could you maybe provide some code you have tried which does not work? The module that isn't working, the command you ran. This question is a bit too vague.

Comment: most likely: you pip installed into one python installation and are trying to run from another.

Comment: It might be that you installed a module, but the way to import it is different then it seems, like pillow should be imported PIL